# AgGrid: Wrong row order from "Copy with header" since v25

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a serverSide Aggrid with the built-in "Copy with Header" context menu to allow user to copy all rows from grid and paste to Excel. The expected outcome is that once pasted to excel, the row order should be the same as the grid. (e.g if col x is sorted in grid, then excel should follow that sequence once pasted). This is true before I upgrade the Aggrid version to v25.0.1 from v24.1.0. Now with v25 the order is almost random.

I checked the changelog and github and did not find any breaking changes that could have impacted clipboard in this way except 2 changes:

- use of browser clipboard api
- major restructure around Server Side Model

I have tried to set the new "storeType" to "partial" and "full" it didn't make any difference. Also I do have unique rowIds that feeds the new getRowId method. Nothing else is changed.

I also tried the built-in "export to excel" feature in v25, this feature respects the order correctly!!

Is this the expectation going forward since v25?

Thank you